# Bean validation and consistent value objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, domain-driven-design

I am using domain-driven design for a current project, which is a Java-based Spring Boot REST-API. Therefore, it should not be possible to create inconsistent value objects, and my problem sits right there.

I want to implement bean validation to provide clear error responses for my consumers. However, the bean validation is not able to validate all required fields because the process will be interrupted by the already existing constructor validation of my value objects. If invalid data gets passed, an exception will be thrown, and the bean validation process will be ended instantaneously.

The constructor validation within my value objects is mandatory and can't be removed.

(I am using @Validated on class level, @Valid on complex objects and @Pattern/NotNull... on primitive constructor parameter)

A possible solution might be to create inconsistent value objects during deserialization by using a custom deserializer and the value objects' default constructor.

Sadly, I am not sure how to implement this. How can I trigger bean validation in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I can see here is a mix of validations of your request with domain object.

You should separate a business logic of your bean which represent a domain object from data incoming from external world.

For example:

You require a dataset which incoming to your controller in a request object.
It can be Json mapped to an java object. This object can be validated via jakarta library. Here you check @NonNull, @SomeOther field validations.

When something is wrong validated in this part of process, you can create a response with validation error.

And remember, this is an error of request data, not a domain bean or a process.

When request data is validated correctly in the next step you should pass this request to factory/constructor to create a domain object or you should create a command with data for a process handler.

This domain object or command should be validated against defined DOMAIN rules before creation.

I proposed my solution. It can be done also in the other way but I think it is the simplest way.

You can also look at this github repo: https://github.com/krzysztofslusarski/jug-hex
where is shown ddd in practice (without restAPI, but this is only an input interface, so it can be replaced by other thing).

Answer (score 0):

If its an option don't use bean validation.

I like my object to have "zero time invalid state" and so everything is validated in the constructor.

Comment: it's a technical choice and not his problem... Bean validation or constructor validation are the same in his case.